# Change default template of django-postman

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

How do I change templates of django-postman? I try to make my own inbox and write template but i am stuck basically.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'postman',
'app',
```

]

my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [

url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^messages/',include('postman.urls',namespace='postman',app_name='postman')),]
```

when i open browser and i go to 
127.0.0.1:8000/messages/inbox 
i got this template

[image: screenshot of browser]

is there any way to change these template and make my own inbox ?

Comment: Please post your attempts so far. Saying you are stuck is not enough information for someone to help you figure out what you are doing wrong.

Comment: You can essentially override the template with your custom template. Have you added the django-postman app after your app in settings.py ?

Comment: @Romaan I edit my post and as you can see postman is before my 'app' application. How do I override it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of INSTALLED_APPS as shown below (Also suggested in my comment):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'app',
'postman',
]
```

Then in your app create `templates` folder. Within template folder create `postman` folder and you can create files like `base.html` or `base_folder.html` and override the custom files and the view. I have tried this and ensured it works.

Extra info: I created base.html within myapp/templates/postman folder:

```
{% load i18n %}{% load postman_tags %}
{% block title %}{% trans "Messaging" %}{% endblock %}
{% block extrahead %}{{ block.super }}
<link type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" href="
{# dj v1.4 #}{% load static %}{% static 'postman/css/postman.css' %}
{# dj v1.3 #}{# {{ STATIC_URL }}postman/css/postman.css #}
{# dj v1.2 #}{# {{ MEDIA_URL }}postman/css/postman.css #}
" />{% endblock %}
{% block postman_menu %}
<h1>Hello</h1>
{% endblock %}
```